# Incrementar numero de itens em uma cesta - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Olá, estou montando uma cesta de itens, é bem simples, quando adiciono um item o numero da cesta deve ser incrementado `i++` e o valor da cesta deve sair do 0 para 1, isso acontece com apenas um item se ele recebe o evento de click ele incrementa na cesta +1, mas se clico no segundo item ele decrementa o  numero de itens da cesta e se clico novamente ele incrementa.  O que eu quero é que cada item ao receber evento de click ele incremente na cesta +1 e que quando eu tirar da cesta ele tire aquele que recebeu o evento de click.

```js
var btnAdd = document.querySelectorAll(".btnAdd");
var nItens = document.querySelector(".numeroItens");
nItens.textContent = 0;
var numItens = nItens.textContent;
click = 1;

btnAdd.forEach(function(botao) {
  botao.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (click == 1) {
      numItens++;
      nItens.textContent = numItens;
      var produto = this.parentElement;
      console.log(produto);

      produto.style.opacity = ".3";
      click = 0;
    } else {
      numItens--;
      nItens.textContent = numItens;
      var produto = this.parentElement;
      produto.style.opacity = "1";
      click = 1;

    }
  })

})
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
}

.header {
  background: #F8CB00;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 10%;
}

.logo {
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.detalhes {
  margin-left: 150px;
}

.acesso {
  width: max-content;
  /* position: relative; */
  /* display: block; */
  float: right;
}

.btnEntrar {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

.btnCriar {
  padding: 7px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #F8CB00;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #fff;
  margin-left: 10px;
}


/* Buscar */

.buscar {
  top: 70px;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0;
}

.buscar>* {
  display: inline-block;
}

.campoBuscar input::placeholder {
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.campoBuscar input {
  padding: 5px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 39px;
  padding-left: 40px;
  width: 600px;
}

.fa-search {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #979797;
}

.buscar button {
  padding: 10px;
  background: #6364D8;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.buscar button>i {
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.buscar button>span {
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  right: -10px;
  position: relative;
  background: #393AB1;
}

.menu {
  position: absolute;
  width: 25%;
  height: 500px;
  background: #fff;
  top: 110px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

.btnAdd {
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  right: -20px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  background: #F8CB00;
}

.main {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.boxProduto {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 150px;
  height: 250px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  /* overflow: hidden; */
  margin: 20px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .6s cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.82, 0.165, 1);
  opacity: 1;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
}

.boxProduto:hover {
  transform: translateY(-5px);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.boxProduto img {
  position: relative;
  width: 130px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.topico {
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
}

.boxProduto .minTitulo {
  margin-top: 5px;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: #001b48;
}

.minPreco {
  font-weight: 800;
  color: #F8CB00;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.minDesc {
  opacity: 0;
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 40px;
  z-index: 99;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #f0f0f0;
}

.close:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.conteudo {
  top: 50%;
  left: 45%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: -98;
  position: fixed;
  width: 60%;
  height: 80vh;
  background: #eef2ff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 100px 500px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .6s cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.82, 0.165, 1);
  transition-delay: .2s;
}

.slide {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 55%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
}

.caixaConteudo {
  float: right;
  padding: 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
  width: 45%;
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif
}

.caixaConteudo .classificacao {
  position: relative;
  border-left: 2px #018abe solid;
  width: max-content;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.caixaConteudo .classificacao .tit {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #03475a;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.caixaConteudo .classificacao .cores {
  color: #03475a;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}

.preco {
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  font-size: 28px;
  margin: 20px 0;
  font-weight: 100;
  /* opacity: 0; */
  color: #001b48;
  transition: all .5s cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.82, 0.165, 1);
}

.titulo {
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  font-size: 28px;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.anime::after {
  content: '';
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #eef2ff;
  animation: nome 1s;
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

@keyframes nome {
  0% {
    width: 100%;
    left: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    left: 100%;
    width: 0%;
  }
}

.descricao {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 20px;
  left: -5%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .5s cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.82, 0.165, 1);
  transition-delay: .8s;
}

.Tdesc {
  display: block;
  letter-spacing: 7px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.Txdesc {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.btnComprar {
  padding: 15px 40px;
  border: none;
  background: #02457a;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-top: 50px;
  left: -5%;
  transition: all .5s;
  transition-delay: .7s;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0;
}

.quant {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 80px;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 200;
}

.quant #menos,
.quant #mais {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 2px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: #969696;
  padding: 0 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <title>Loja - Adidas</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></i>Cesta<span class="numeroItens"></span></button>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="boxProduto">
      <img id="imgVitrine" src="img/arroz02.png">
      <div class="topico">
        <div class="minTitulo">Arroz Urbano</div>
        <div class="minPreco">R$ 2.54</div>
        <div class="minDesc"></div>
      </div>
      <button class="btnAdd">+</button>
    </div>
    <div class="boxProduto">
      <img id="imgVitrine" src="img/arroz2.png">
      <div class="topico">
        <div class="minTitulo">Arroz Qualitá</div>
        <div class="minPreco">R$ 2.74</div>
        <div class="minDesc"></div>
      </div>
      <button class="btnAdd">+</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pelo que dá para observar, ambos eventos estão usando a mesma flag - a variável `click`, para checar se um produto já foi clicado.

Ao se clicar no primeiro produto, a variável click é setada para 0.
Então quando o segundo produto é clicado, como sua variável click ainda é 0, e seu código considera que você está deselecionando um produto.

Para manter controle de qual produto já foi selecionado, você pode passar um novo atributo para eles, ou então adicioná-los a uma lista, ou criar um input escondido. No exemplo eu uso o atributo `clicked`. Note que eu posso utilizá-lo mesmo antes de inicia-lo - um atributo não iniciado retorna `undefined`, que funciona de forma similar a um `false`.

```js
var btnAdd = document.querySelectorAll(".btnAdd");
var nItens = document.querySelector(".numeroItens");
nItens.textContent = 0;
var numItens = nItens.textContent;

btnAdd.forEach(function(botao){
    botao.addEventListener("click", function(){
        if(!this.clicked){
            numItens++;
            nItens.textContent = numItens;
            var produto = this.parentElement;
            console.log(produto);
            
            produto.style.opacity = ".3";
            this.clicked = true;
        }
        else{
            numItens--;
            nItens.textContent = numItens;
            var produto = this.parentElement;
            produto.style.opacity = "1";
            this.clicked = false;

        }
    })

})
```

```css
html,body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
}
.header{
    background: #F8CB00; 
    height: 150px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px 10%;
}
.logo{
    position: relative;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 800;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-size: 22px;
}
.detalhes{
    margin-left: 150px;
}
.acesso{
    width: max-content;
    /* position: relative; */
    /* display: block; */
    float: right;
}
.btnEntrar{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    
}
.btnCriar{
    padding: 7px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #F8CB00;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #fff;
    margin-left:10px;
}
/* Buscar */
.buscar{
    top: 70px;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 0;
}
.buscar > *{
    display: inline-block;
}
.campoBuscar input::placeholder{
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 15px;
}
.campoBuscar input{
    padding: 5px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 39px;
    padding-left: 40px;
    width: 600px;
}
.fa-search{
    position: absolute;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #979797;
}
.buscar button{
    padding: 10px;
    background: #6364D8;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.buscar button > i{
    padding-right: 5px;
}
.buscar button > span{
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    right: -10px;
    position: relative;
    background: #393AB1;
    
}
.menu{
    position: absolute;
    width: 25%;
    height: 500px;
    background: #fff;
    top: 110px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
.btnAdd{
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    right: -20px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: #F8CB00;
}
















.main{
    width: 100%;
    
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.boxProduto{    
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 150px;
    height: 250px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    /* overflow: hidden; */
    margin: 20px 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all .6s cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.82, 0.165, 1);
    opacity: 1;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
}
.boxProduto:hover{
    transform: translateY(-5px);
    cursor: pointer;
}
.boxProduto img{
    position: relative;
    width: 130px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
.topico{
    position: absolute;
    background: #fff;
    padding:10px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius:  0 0 5px 5px;
}
.boxProduto .minTitulo{
    margin-top: 5px;
    font-weight: 100;
    color: #001b48;

}
.minPreco{
    font-weight: 800;
    color: #F8CB00;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
.minDesc{
    opacity: 0;
}
.close{
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    height: 40px;
    z-index: 99;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: #f0f0f0;
}
.close:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
}

.conteudo{
    top: 50%;
    left: 45%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    z-index: -98;
    position: fixed;
    width: 60%;
    height: 80vh;
    background: #eef2ff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 100px 500px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    overflow: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .6s cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.82, 0.165, 1);
    transition-delay: .2s;
}
.slide{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 55%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    
}

.caixaConteudo{
    float: right;
    padding: 30px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100%;
    width:45%;
    position: relative;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif
}
.caixaConteudo .classificacao{
    position: relative;
    border-left:2px #018abe solid;
    width: max-content;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
.caixaConteudo .classificacao .tit{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #03475a;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-weight: 500;
}
.caixaConteudo .classificacao .cores{
    color: #03475a;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 12px;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
}
.preco {
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-size: 28px;
    margin: 20px 0;
    font-weight: 100;
    /* opacity: 0; */
    color: #001b48;
    transition: all .5s cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.82, 0.165, 1);
}
.titulo{
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    font-size: 28px;
    line-height: 20px;
    font-weight: 100;
}
.anime::after{
    content: '';
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 0%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #eef2ff;
    animation: nome 1s;
    animation-delay: 0s;    
}
@keyframes nome{
    0%{
        width: 100%;
        left: 0%;
    }
    100%{
        left: 100%;
        width: 0%;
    }
}
.descricao{
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 20px;
    left: -5%;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .5s cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.82, 0.165, 1);
    transition-delay: .8s;
}
.Tdesc{
    display: block;
    letter-spacing: 7px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.Txdesc{
    font-size: 12px;
}
.btnComprar{
    padding: 15px 40px;
    border: none;
    background: #02457a;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 50px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-top: 50px;
    left: -5%;
    transition: all .5s;
    transition-delay: .7s;
    position: relative;
    opacity: 0;
}
.quant{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 80px;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: 200;
}
.quant #menos, .quant #mais{
    position: relative;
    bottom: 2px;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 100;
    color: #969696;
    padding: 0 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <title>Loja - Adidas</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></i>Cesta<span class="numeroItens"></span></button>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="boxProduto">
            <img id="imgVitrine" src="img/arroz02.png">
            <div class="topico">
                <div class="minTitulo">Arroz Urbano</div>
                <div class="minPreco">R$ 2.54</div>
                <div class="minDesc"></div>
            </div>
            <button class="btnAdd">+</button>
        </div>
        <div class="boxProduto">
            <img id="imgVitrine" src="img/arroz2.png">
            <div class="topico">
                <div class="minTitulo">Arroz Qualitá</div>
                <div class="minPreco">R$ 2.74</div>
                <div class="minDesc"></div>
            </div>
            <button class="btnAdd">+</button>
        </div>        
    </div>
        
</body>

</html>
```